# Store files in clipboard in python (cross-platform)

Tags: python, file, clipboard

I'm trying to store a file in the clipboard in windows mac and linux.
For ex: running the script will put a file / files in the clipboard and now I can ctrl+v wherever i want to paste the files.

for windows i have written this code in c#:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace file2clip
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringCollection paths = new StringCollection();
            foreach (string s in args) paths.Add(s);
            Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
        }
    }
}
```

then implement in python:

```py
import subprocess

def files_to_win_clip(files: tuple):
    subprocess.call(f'file2clip.exe {files}')
```

For linux i found xclip which allows to copy and paste files but it doesnt go to the default clipboard so I can't paste (with ctrl+v) the file wherever I'm at.

I might need some help on how to make it work on linux and mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of python modules to do this. One of them is https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

The c program in this way is not needed you can read the file in python as text or do all logic that you want and put it in the clipboard.

For full file copy you can use this snippet :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

data = QtCore.QMimeData()
url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('c:\\foo.file')
data.setUrls([url])

app.clipboard().setMimeData(data)
```

Comment: pyperclip cannot copy files to the clpiboard. as well as pyclip, only the content of the files to the clipboard, but not the files itself

Comment: So you can give a look to QMimeData that is part of pyQt4 it should help you

Comment: I'm going to edit my unswer whit an example

Comment: you should know: Tthe qt application needs to still be running in order to paste. It is possible on windows to call `OleFlushClipboard` in order to put the data itself to the clipboard (rather than just a link), but it's a bit [complicated](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/com/win32com/test/testClipboard.py). I am unaware of a solution for MacOS or Linux

Comment: @Aaron thank you but I dont what to put the data, only a link so i can `ctrl` + `v` the file anywhere. One problem is that this code above doesn't work for linux... after using `app.clipboard().setMimeData(data)` in linux, I couldn't paste the file with `ctrl` + `v`

Comment: @lordcommander like I said, you need to ensure the `QApplication` is still around in order to be able to paste. If python exits, it won't be available anymore. calling `app.exec_()` will keep the application around until you kill it by closing the terminal.

Comment: @Aaron I already did that this is just an example in the question above... As I said it works fine with windows

Comment: @lordcommander and what I'm saying is that is what I had to do to get it to work with linux... (ubuntu 20.04) On windows before OleFlushClipboard is called, the clipboard only contains a pointer to the mime data, and "flushing" it forces the mime data (IDataObject) to the clipboard so it doesn't become just a null pointer when the program exits

Comment: @Aaron, Didn't work in linux for me... If you got it to work can you please post the code as an answer below?

Comment: @lordcommander, the mime data is being put to the clipboard.. the code is exactly the same. it's up to the application where you paste to request the correct mime type from the clipboard

Comment: @Aaron Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232710/discussion-between-lordcommander-and-aaron).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but `xclip` can be used as follows:

```sh
$ xclip -selection clipboard [FILES]
```

This copies the files' text to the clipboard; I'm not sure if this is the behaviour you are looking for though.

Comment: Looking for a way to copy the file itself, so I can `ctrl`+`v` it later at any place

Comment: I see. In that case, `xclip`  can't help you (to my knowledge at least).